# How can I return non-matches query values in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo database with documents like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "b"
  }
]
```

Given a set of values, I would like to know which values are missing from the database. So, I would like to query Mongo and return only the non-matching values from the query.

For example, for the array `["b", "c"]` and the collection above, I would like to get the result `["c"]`.

How can I query Mongo and return the non-matching values from the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to get a list of all the existing values and then use [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to get the actual difference.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      values: {
        $addToSet: "$value"
      }
    }
  },

  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      missing: {
        $setDifference: [["b", "c"], "$values"]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/lhfV8SGCjlo